# Why is this condition sufficient for a topological space to be irreducible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-theory, schemes

I am studying an article about the space of valuation rings by Koji Sekiguchi and while trying to establish a morphism of ringed spaces, he used the fact that the space $Zar(K\mid A) $ of valuation rings  contained in a fixed field K and containing a ring A, equipped with the basis of topology:
$$
\Sigma = \{Zar(K\mid E) \mid E \ \text{is a finite subset of} \ K\}  \quad \quad (1)
$$
is irreducible.
The justification he used is a result about singletons in this space:
$$
\overline{\{R\}} = \{R^\prime \in Zar(K \mid A) \mid R^\prime \subset R \} \quad \quad (2)
$$
I cannot see how $(2)$ would lead to the fact that $Zar(K\mid A)$ is irreducible.

(a topological space is said to be irreducible if it cannot be expressed as a union of two proper closed subets.)

Here's a citation for the article:

*Sekiguchi, Koji*, [**Prüfer domain and affine scheme**](http://dx.doi.org/10.3836/tjm/1270132261), Tokyo J. Math. 13, No. 2, 259-275 (1990). [ZBL0726.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0726.14001).

Comment: You should probably include a link to the specific article that you are studying from.

Comment: It's done. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Equation (2) implies that the closure of the point $K\in Zar(K\mid A)$ is the whole space, since $K$ contains every other valuation ring. A space which is the closure of a single point is irreducible, since if you decompose it as a union of two closed subsets then one of them must contain that point and thus be the whole space.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was indeed obvious. is there any references or exercises I can work on to get comfortable with this kind of topologies. I am still struggling with understanding how open subsets in this topology look like, I would really appreciate something not very hard to read to get past this struggle.